# Xcode 9 Server "fork: Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, xcode-bots, xcode-server

In my iOS project i have some run script files in my directory. When using the new Xcode 9 Server feature "Run test in parallel" the xcodebuild failes because it can not open so many times the same file.

The file to be called is here:

```
/my-ios-project/scripts/my-script.sh
```

I call it two times in my run script which was never a problem

```
"${SOURCE_ROOT}"/scripts/my-script.sh first-call-arg
"${SOURCE_ROOT}"/scripts/my-script.sh second-call-arg
```

Error message says "fork: Resource temporarily unavailable". As far as i know this is because it tries to open one file too many times.

```
/bin/sh -c \"/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/4449e5bcbfaa89a18949b4b093185630/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates.noindex/my-ios-project.build/Release-iphonesimulator/my-scheme.build/Script-21A92E061D93E0B700C4948E.sh\"
/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/4449e5bcbfaa89a18949b4b093185630/Source/my-ios-project/scripts/my-script.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
/Users/xcodeserver/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/4449e5bcbfaa89a18949b4b093185630/Source/my-ios-project/scripts/my-script.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Anyone experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there would be a recursive call involved. Check that you are not naming your bash functions and external functions the same.